# How to arrange combinations by odds and evens in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have the following code to make a list of combinations of 5 integers from 1 up to 20:

```
from itertools import combinations
combos = []
for x in combinations(range(1,21,5)):
    combos.append(x)
```

How can I extract only the combinations that have, say 4 odd numbers (and 1 even number) and put them in a separate list?

I tried writing some code to make lists of the odd and even values:

```
odds = []
evens = []
for y in range(21):
   if y%2 == 0:
     evens.append(y)
  else:
     odds.append(y)
```

and set up another loop like so:

```
odd4_even1: []
for z in combos:
    # if number of odds in combos == 4:
        # odd4_even1.append(z)
```

How can I implement the commented-out part?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be clear: the question is "given five numbers, how can I check whether 4 of them are even?" - right? Okay, so **what does that have to do with** combinations, putting things into lists, etc. etc.? Please read [ask] and [mre], and try to focus questions on the part that you are actually wondering about - only show context to the extent that's needed to understand that problem. And then - **what exactly is causing difficulty**? You know how to check whether a number is even; you have a variable `z` that contains the five numbers you want to look at...

Comment: I [edit]ed the question to show how to ask a question directly and clearly, [without](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) anything irrelevant. (I also fixed a typo in the code, since it seems clear that you were not asking about any problem that typo would have caused.) Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**; we [don't want](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160) your thanks and [don't care about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) your self-assessment of your skill level. We care about a clear, directly asked question.

Comment: But hopefully, now that it's written out like this, it should be clear that it **does not matter** where the values in `combos` came from, and that the question is **not about** combinatorics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add up the number of odd numbers that are in x in the combination for loop and sort them into groups based on the odd number count without ever having to make an even or odd list, or having to iterate the full list over again at all.

You can use a dictionary where the keys are the number of odd integers in the sequences, and the values will be a list containing all of the sequences containing that many odd integers.

```
from itertools import combinations

groups = {}
for x in combinations (range(1,21),5):
    odd_count = sum([1 for i in x if i%2 == 1])
    groups.setdefault(odd_count, [])
    groups[odd_count].append(x)

print({i:len(groups[i]) for i in groups})
```

OUTPUT:

```
{3: 5400, 2: 5400, 4: 2100, 1: 2100, 5: 252, 0: 252}
```

So if you wanted the list that contains 4 odd numbers and 1 even you would just use `groups[4]`  or if you wanted the group that contains 1 odd and 4 evens use `groups[1]`

---

If for some reason you really wanted to do it the way you are currently using you could do something like this:

```
odd4_even1 = []
for z in combos:
    total = 0
    for num in z:
        if num in odds:
            total += 1
    if total == 4:
        odd4_even1.append(z)

print(len(odd4_even1)) # 2100
```

Comment: I would like to thank both, Karl Knechtel and Alexander for editing and answering my question. I hope one day I could become as proficient as both or you are in order to help members of this wonderful community, Thank you, thank you, thank you.